# Where does the Server information come from in a Workspace definition?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have an error where everytime I open Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> TF205020: Could not connect to server ‘tfs.server.com\collectionname’. This server was used in your last session, but it might be offline or unreachable. Confirm that the server is available on the network. To attempt to connect again, or to a different server, click ‘Connect To Team Foundation Server’ in Team Explorer or the Team menu.
>
> The server returned the following error: TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server tfs.server.com\collectionname.
>
> Technical information (for administrator):
>     The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.We were unable to automatically populate your Visual Studio Online accounts.

This is an on-premise TFS 2013 Update 4.

I always get this error when starting Visual Studio and I have to go into Team Explorer and explicitly connect to the server to get it to connect correctly.

The issue is that the URL in the error above is wrong.  It is missing a virtual directory.

- **Correct URL:** https://tfs.server.com/tfs/collectionname
- **Url in Error:** https://tfs.server.com/collectionname

As you can see the **tfs** directory is missing.  I can see that the server is setup correctly in Team Explorer and I can also see that it is setup incorrectly in the Workspace configuration.  Here is a picture of the workspace config.

[image]

My question is:

**Where does this URL come from and why is it different to that stored in Team Explorer?**

Answer (score 0):

The URL is stored in your sln file.  You can either do File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control

Or you could crack open the sln file in notepad and change it there.

Comment: I don't see how this can be true.  The URL that is wrong is at a Workspace mapping level.  The error appears when opening Visual Studio without opening a solution.  Edited the question to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend brute force approach first.  Delete that workspace and create new one from scratch.

Comment: This is a fresh workspace.  I'm not sure how I would "brute force" this.  I delete the workspace and re-create it and it's the same.  It doesn't fix it.